# Electron tunneling: transmission>1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, scattering, probability, quantum-tunneling

Assume a simple electron tunneling scheme from medium 1 into medium 2. By applying the boundary conditions (continuity of the wave function and its derivative at the interface), it is straightforward to show that the transfer matrix from medium 1 into medium 2 has the following elements:

t11 = 0.5*(1+k1/k2);

t12 = 0.5*(1-k1/k2);

t21 = t12; 
t22 = t11;

where k = 2*pi*sqrt(2m(E-V))/h, h being Planck's constant, m electron mass, E its energy and V is potential.

To find transmission/reflection, I convert this transfer matrix to a scattering matrix by using

S11 = t11 - t12*t21/t22;

S12 = t12/t22;

S21 = -t21/t22;

S22 = 1/t22;

This scattering matrix allows us calculate the outgoing waves (B1(reflection) and A2 (transmission)) from the incoming waves (A1=1, and B2=0).

T =  abs(A2)^2/abs(A1)^2; % transmission coefficient

Now comes the critical part. If we calculate transmission from medium 1 to 2, we may get transmission values that are larger than 1!

Blake J. Eliasson does some relevant calculation in his PhD thesis. You can easily google it and find it: his thesis title is "Metal-insulator-metal diodes for solar energy conversion". He mentions on page 63 that:

"When the effective mass changes across an interface, we must multiply the transfer matrix by sqrt(k1/k2) to ensure tunneling probabilities do not exceed unity."

Now I have the following questions:

- How do we know that the electron effective mass changes across an interface?
- Where does the ratio sqrt(k1/k2) comes from?
- Why should we change the transfer matrix that we calculated? Then, the boundary conditions at the interface will be violated.

Thanks,
Ali

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quantum tunneling larger than 1 transmission](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516365/)

Comment: Hi Ali Naqavi. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.